# Is it best practise to use a shared mailbox as AWS root user address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cloud

Or is it better to use a mailbox with a password locked in a safe, because everyone should use their own IAM account?

In case of a Shared mailbox someone could use the password reset feature to gain access to the root account.

Comment: "everyone should use their own IAM account" ideally, SSO.  But there are a few legitimate uses of the root account and its email address could appropriately be a distribution list that includes all top level administrators at the org.

Comment: [AWS themselves recommend](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html) you only use the root account for the handful of required reasons, otherwise use administrative or more locked down accounts.  More practically, it's best if users us their own account.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a shared password vault for the root credentials, including the one-time password. If you use Google for email you can use the plus sign to create a dedicated address for the root account. For example:

1. Create a Google group and add all the appropriate parties (e.g. `awsroot@foo.com`).
2. Set the email address for the AWS root user to `awsroot+account1@foo.com`.
3. Set up the MFA for the root user.
4. Add the credentials (email address, password, and MFA) to a new item in a shared 1Password vault.

Now anyone with access to the vault can use the credentials. Any updates to the root account (e.g. password resets, email address changes, etc) will result in an email being sent to the shared address. Everyone gets a copy.